# empty oracle global temporary table for where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some GTTs that are filled with data and later used for WHERE clauses `(WHERE x in (SELECT * FROM gtt))`. However sometimes I don't have data for a temporary table or don't want to filter by it.

If I understand it correctly, GTTs are instantiated when I insert something and are there for the session. Is there a way to instantiate an empty table so when I use the WHERE IN SELECT it doesn't throw an error (which it does now)?
Or do I have to create the SELECT statement with IFs to selectively only include a WHERE for the gtts that should be used?

Currently the structure looks like this:

```
IF(data)
INSERT INTO GTT1 SELECT ...
END IF;
```

(for several gtts)

```
SELECT x.data, x.more, a.a, a.b 
FROM table1 x, table2 a 
WHERE x.key in (SELECT * From gtt1) AND x.a = a.a;
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: instead of AND u should use WHERE. SELECT x.data, x.more, a.a, a.b 
FROM table x, table2 a 
WHERE x.key in (SELECT * From gtt1 WHERE x.a = a.a;

Comment: Obviously you have edited your code to remove sensitive information. Fair enough. But you must be careful to retain sufficient information for us to understand what's going on. For instance, right now your sample SELECT won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the WHERE clause of your `INSERT INTO GTT` such that no rows are found.